# Is 'favor A to B' correct?

Tags: comparison

> Utah is big business for the dessert trade, with many residents favoring sweets and soda shops to a bar or cafe.

The original article is [this](https://www.wsj.com/articles/cookies-so-good-were-being-sued-welcome-to-utahs-bakery-wars-11670339955?st=klbr4pv4dz8jjym&reflink=desktopwebshare_permalink).

I understand the latter phrase as Utah residents like sweets and soda shops more than a bar or cafe. I know you don't use 'favor A to B' as the meaning like that, not like 'prefer A to B'. You would say 'favor A over B'.

Am I misunderstanding the phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not *incorrect*.

This is one of those choices of wording that an English teacher might mark in red in order to "correct" it, but the meaning is perfectly clear, and doesn't sound wrong to a native speaker. There's no special hidden meaning.

You're right that 'prefer A to B' or 'favor A over B' would sound more natural; perhaps, the author started with one phrase, then changed it partially and didn't notice the hybrid wording.

As with most things in human language, "correct" is a relative term :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "favour A to B" is correct.

It's much more common to use "over", but "to" is fine. It's more informal than  using "over".